# Return URL with GET variable in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to specify some GET variable in the URL returned from Spring, something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html?page=home
```

It would be similar in principle to something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jobs")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String showHome() {
        return "index.html?page=home";
    }
}
```

But obviously this will cause an error since this return value should resolve only to a filename.

How can I achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: This seems like an A/B problem. Why do you need to display a parameterized URL? Frontend routing?

Comment: @TheHeadRush what is an "A/B" problem?  if we can extract parameters from a URL using Spring, why can we not add them?  it seems counter-intuitive to provide a method for reading but not for writing such a variable...

Comment: An A/B problem is thinking the problem is A (for example, how can i return a parameterized URL from an `@Controller` method) when the real problem is B (for example, how can i tell my frontend routing system that the initial page load should route to the home view). That's why i asked why you need a parameterized URL.

Comment: @TheHeadRush regardless of the purpose, it seems like Spring should be able to do something as simple as create a parameterized URL.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index.html")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getPage(@QueryParam("page") String pageId) {
        return "index.html?page=" + pageId;
    }
}
```

It really depends what you want to happen when the `@GetMapping` is hit. Right now it returns a `String` which could just be the body of the response + a `200` (OK) HTTP status code.